# $http.post within a $http.post, return response is not updated directly

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a function, it has a **$http.post** for login purpose. If success, another **$http.post** will call a php file that fetches data from database. The problem is that, when I am trying to load the data from **localStorage** it returns me null. Why is it so?

```
$scope.loginUser = function () 
{
    var data = 
    {
        username: $scope.loginInfo.username,
        password: $scope.loginInfo.password
    }
    $http.post("endpoints/login.php", data).success(function(response)
    {
        if(response==="ERROR")
        {
            //DONT DO ANYTHING
        }    
        else
        {
            localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log("loginController: name is this "  + localStorage);
            fetchDataFunction(data);
            $state.go("application");


            //$state.go("application", result);
        }     
    }).error(function(error)
    {
        console.error(error);
    });

}

fetchDataFunction = function(data)
{
    $http.post("endpoints/fetchData.php", data).success(function(response)
    {
        localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(response));
    }).error(function(error)
    {
        console.error(error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Flow process doesn't make any sense. Why wouldn't you fetchData in the application state?

Comment: Hi sir, my intention is to fetch all data from database right after login and load the application page and display all the data there.

Comment: Right...but the norm is to load what is needed by the state itself. Could do it in a `resolve` so it is all available before the controller and template loads. Right now you are switching states before the fetchData request completes

Comment: Sorry I am new to web programming, I have no idea which way is the best or correct way. Thank you for the advice, I will look into the resolve function. But do you have any idea why is it giving me such odd behavior shouldn't the data be loaded and store in my localstorage?

Comment: No because it's important to understand that ajax requests are asynchronous. That request could take a second lets say but switching states is done in milliseconds...although it might need to ajx to get template but you have no way to know which finishes first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the `$http.post`, which will return a promise, and then all your code will work in the correct order:

```
$scope.loginUser = function () {
    login($scope.loginInfo).then(function (response) {

        localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log("loginController: name is this " + localStorage.getItem("token"));

        fetchDataFunction(data).then(function () {

            localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(response));
            console.log(localStorage.getItem("data"));
            $state.go("application");

        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });

    }).catch(function (response) {

        console.error(error);

    });
};

var login = function (user) {
    return post("endpoints/login.php", user);
};

var fetchDataFunction = function (data) {
    return post("endpoints/fetchData.php", data);
};

var post = function (url, data) {

    var deferred = $q.defer;

    $http.post(url, data).then(function (response) {
        if (response === "ERROR") {
            deferred.reject(response);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(response);
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        deferred.reject(error);
    });

    return deferred;
};
```

Notes:

- You will need to make sure you inject $q into your controller along with $http
- You should use `localStorage.getItem()` when recalling information from the global object
- You should use `then/catch` instead of `success/error`, as these are now depreciated: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http